# PlotRange manually set only one side of plotrange

Tags: plotting

Is there any easy way to manually set only one side of the plot range and let the other one be set by either the automatic value or the max value (either option would be acceptable, which ever one is easier)? So I would like to specify something like

```
ListPlot[data,PlotRange->{Automatic,{1,max}}]
```

To alter the y plot range to {1,max value in data}. I know I can find this value max by hand for each plot, but since I use this kind of option often I would like to avoid having a separate line for this each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, All}}`.

An example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[100, {100, 2}];
data = Append[data, {{500, 50}, {50, 500}}];

Row[{ListPlot[data,  ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotLabel -> "PlotRange -> Automatic"], 
  ListPlot[data,  ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "PlotRange->All"]
  ListPlot[data,  ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {70, All}}, 
    PlotLabel -> "PlotRange -> {Automatic, {70, All}}"  ]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

This works in both directions. You can use `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {All, 50}}` to have the vertical plot range go from the minimum of data to 50:

```
ListPlot[data,  ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {All, 50}}, 
  PlotLabel->"PlotRange -> {Automatic, {All, 50}}"  ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[100, {100, 2}];
data = Append[data, {{500, 50}, {50, 500}}];
```

Even shorter you can specify the Y-axis `PlotRange` only.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {0, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The default for the X-axis is `Automatic`

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting too. By the way maybe `ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, 50}]` would illustrate the point better since it answers the question how to alter just the upper or lower endpoint.